# Generating a list of include directories, and project files from a CMakeLists.txt

Tags: emacs, cmake

I'd like to use emacs to work on my project that is built using CMake, while this generally works fine, I'd like to implement better project management commands. Is there a simple way to generate some sort of file that acts as a listing of the project files.

It seems that the best way may just be some set of CMake macros that do a custom write to a file, is there perhaps any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience with CMake.  But there are a couple of approaches to solving this.

The canonical way is to generate a TAGS table as a part of your buid process.  You will get symbol completion/navigation on top of easy access to file-list.  And ctags is hyper fast.  I'll leave you to google how to do that specifically, hint: [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags).

Alternatively, you can get a Emacs project management package like EDE, eproject, mk-project that defines the concept of a project.  See [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProjectSettings).

Answer (score 0):

You can look onto [CEDET](http://cedet.sf.net) mailing list - CMake support was discussed not so long time ago, and at least one person is actively working on CMake support in EDE (CEDET's project management)